# Does LinkedIn act illegally if asking me whether I want to share my email contacts and send them invitations?

Tags: gdpr, social-media

From time to time LinkedIn asks me whether I would like upload emails of my contacts. In terms of GDPR I would say it is not allowed action if I do not have signatures of my contacts that they agree I can do so.

But, does LinkedIn doing something wrong if it asks me to do an action which might be illegal, without giving any hint regarding that? And isn't wrong to further process the private data if there is a possibility I haven't cared about GDPR?